# How to create a click animation for items in a RecycleView

Tags: android, android-animation

I have been googling around to determine how I get a click animation for items in a RecycleView, something like "click/touch feedback".

I can see  my items in the view, but there is no real reaction to when I press/click on them. I have a downsized version of this project:

https://github.com/writtmeyer/recyclerviewdemo/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/grokkingandroid/samplesapp/samples/recyclerviewdemo

Does anyone know how to get click animations for items in a RecycleView?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is very easy to do. In the layout file of the view you're inflating for each row of your `RecycleView`, set the top-level view to be both clickable and focusable. Then, set the background of that view to `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground`. Based on the GitHub project you posted, it looks like the view you're inflating for each row is `item_demo_01.xml`. So, that layout would now look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container_list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <include layout="@layout/common_item_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I'll look into this as soon as possible. This seems to be less cumbersome and bloated, so I'll try that out and let you know shortly =)

Comment: @Ted glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this using you viewholder in your RecyclerAdapter class.

```
//this goes in your recyclerView adapter....
  /**
     * View holder for workouts
     */
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTitleView;
        public TextView mTView1;
        public View homeView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            this.homeView = itemLayoutView;
            this.mTitleView = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.workoutItemTitleText);
            this.mTView1 = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.workoutItemWorkoutSets);
            homeView.setOnClickListener(new ON)
        }
    }

     //other code.....

  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WorkoutViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.mTView1.setText("");
        viewHolder.mTitleView.setText("");
       //pass the position to the view in the onclick listener
        viewHolder.homeView.setId(position);
        viewHolder.homeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //this list item has been clicked, do something. maybe use an interface or something to notify your activity/fragment. 
            }
        });
    }

//the rest of your code.....
```

In the onBindViewHolder method you can implement your animation logic for that view and pass that onclick to your activity or fragment. Simply make a custom interface for your recyclerview adapter and make a method like `setMyOnItemClickListener(new MyOnItemClickListener)`. Then when an item is clicked, notify your custom interface and do some action with the click.

Comment: Thx. But I still dont see/get how to do it. And is this really the way to do it? It seems very cumbersome regarding that the idea with Material Design is that it should be easier and a natural part of the development, but this approach seems to be a hack? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: It is kind of a hack but it is one of the few ways to do so. The base RecyclerAdapter class has no "onItemClick" method like list views and grid views do. A recycler view is meant to be super flexible and since that is the case many things about it and its adapter are bare bones to allow you to do what you want as a developer. Unfortunately it is very difficult now to switch to different layout types but this will hopefully change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For those lurking around in future, I had to modify Nathan Walter's answer as follows in order for my thing to work:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

(*foreground* instead of *background*. Because in my case, there was a textview, with its own opaque background, inside the LinearLayout)